# How can a pre-commit git hook runs rspec tests and prevent a commit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rspec, githooks, pre-commit-hook

How can I add a pre-commit hook that will run my rspec tests and if any fail, will not complete the commit.  I can get the tests to run but not prevent the commit on any failure of them

I have copied `.git/hooks/pre-commit.sample` to `.git/hooks/pre-commit`

I've added `rspec spec` near the bottom.

The tests run as part of the commit... but a failure doesn't stop the commit from completing.

```
$ git commit -m'test'
....................................................................................................F.............

Failures:

  1) Link Good url SHOULD be valid
     Failure/Error: expect(link.valid_get?).to be false #true

       expected false
            got true
     # ./spec/models/link_spec.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 32.78 seconds (files took 3.58 seconds to load)
114 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/link_spec.rb:24 # Link Good url SHOULD be valid
[79230846_hook_to_run_tests 6c09570] test
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 x.x
```

Maybe I need a different way to run the rspec tests that will raise the non-zero error I need ?

Currently it is placed at the bottom:

```
    ...
    echo
    echo "  git config hooks.allownonascii true"
    echo
    exit 1
fi

rspec spec

exec git diff-index --check --cached $against --
```

I'm doing all this in a branch (not master).  Didn't know if that was relevant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found that using

```
exec rspec spec
```

in

```
.git/hooks/pre-commit
```

gave me the desired functionality -
commit attempts trigger rspec test runs and the commit only complete if all rspec tests pass.

Comment: If you want to automate this for your project you can add this to your `bin/setup`.
`system "echo 'exec rspec spec' >> .git/hooks/pre-commit"`

Answer (score 1):

If the pre-commit hook itself doing an exit zero, or is it just calling rspec?

It might be all you need to do is add `exit $?` after the rspec call.